# Changing placeholder text with CSS only

Tags: html, css

I am building one of those contact forms that are conversational. Like:

[image]

The problem is that the placeholder text on one of them is very large and would either break into two lines or if I gave it a fixed width, it would break the layout of smaller mobile phones. Yes, I understand the the very simple solution would be to propose a change to the copy for any instance, but going on the fact that it cannot be done, how would I solve swapping the text based on the device width.

My proposed solution was to reduce the text on mobile. Since there they are more flexible with the mobile product, I can make these changes, but the desktop needs to comply with the PSD.

### Demo

Demo on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/GrrObw)

### HTML

```
<input type="text" id="org" name="" placeholder="ORGANIZATION OR COMPANY NAME">
```

### CSS

```
#org{
  display: block;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #org{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 360px;
  }
}
```

It needs to be at least 360px to match the PSD for desktop.

One other option that I have is if I have entirely different inputs, would that work? like

```
<input type="text" id="org" class="orgm" name="" placeholder="ORG/COMPANY">
<input type="text" id="org" class="orgd" name="" placeholder="ORGANIZATION OR COMPANY NAME">


.orgm { //mobile
    display: block;
}
.orgd {
    display: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .orgm{
      display: none;
      width: 96%;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .orgd {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 360px;
      margin: 0;
  }
}
```

I don't want to use jQuery or other javascript based solutions.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Can you create a snippet or fiddle?

Comment: Your solution of having different inputs for different display resolutions would work fine. If you are just submitting a form, make sure all "versions" of the same form element have the same `name` attribute. If you are doing some other stuff with JS, make sure all versions also have the same events on them

Comment: @chiliNUT by giving the same name to different elements it wouldn't carry the risk of the second value replacing the first one, since the variable name is the same?

Comment: @André your right, I didn't think of that, good catch. A way around it would be to submit an array value like "`name=whatever[]`" and then on the serverside only grab the non-empty value. I know this question doesn't specify anything server side which is fine, but I think that's fairly compatible, off top of my head the array syntax works for JSP and PHP

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must keep that copy and are willing to do something a bit hacky, this is where it becomes annoying, but you could try...

```
<div class="input--container">
    <p class="input--placeholder">
        <span class="desktop">ORGANIZATION OR </span>
        COMPANY NAME
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="org" class="input" name="">
</div>

// Hide the long part on mobile
.input--placeholder span { //mobile
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    // Show the full on desktop
    .input--placeholder span {
       display: inline;
    }
}
```

And then you'll just have to position the placeholder text absolutely over the top of the input.

EDIT: You'll also have to hide the placeholder completely when the user is on the input which you can do with input:focus selector